# How best to filter a Seq[Object] by a Map[String, Int] in Scala?

Tags: scala, data-structures

I'm trying to filter a Seq[Object] containing objects by a 
Map[objectid: String, Int] where the Object.id is a key in the Map.

I want to return a new Map containing only the objects whose id's were in the original map with their Int values. So the functions should return Map[Object, Int]

Here is what I have thus far? What is the best way to achieve this?

```
val peopleObjects[Person] = Seq[person1, person2, person3]

val peopleMap[String, Int] = Map[PersonId, Int]

peopleObjects.filter(person[Person] => peopleMap.contains)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting compilation errors, since that's not valid scala. Start with fixing them (or posting them if you need help with them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming choices are a little confusing. I tried to make it a bit clearer but if `id` is a `String` it's unclear what the `Int` represents.

```
class Person(val id: String) {}
val (tom, jan) = (new Person("tom"), new Person("jan"))
val persons = Seq[Person](tom, jan)

val idMap = Map[String, Int]("tom"->4, "jan"->2)

val personMap = persons.filter(p => idMap.contains(p.id))
                       .map(p => p->idMap(p.id))
                       .toMap
personMap(jan)  // res0: Int = 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for making this more clear, what else would I need to do if the persons Seq was now a Future[Seq[Person]] ?

Comment: Use `map()` to peek inside a `Future`. Once inside you can add further processing of the future's _eventual_ result.

Comment: @jwvh What is val (tom,jan)?

Comment: In Scala you can user pattern matching to create and initialize multiple variables at once. When the compiler sees this `val (x,y,z)=(3,5,2)` it matches the tuple on the right by creating three variables in a tuple on the left. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a slightly different approach. Borrowing somewhat from @jwvh:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String)
val tom = Person(4, "tom")
val jan = Person(2, "jan")
val people: Future[Set[Person]] = Future.successful(Set(tom, jan))

val peopleMap = people.map { set =>
   set.map(p => (p -> p.id))(breakOut)
}
```

Basically I think case classes, and especially`breakOut`, are really useful here.